# Memory Allocation C with pointers and structures

Tags: c

I'm trying to write to a pointer by accessing it and allocating memory from other function. But after a few iterations on the while statement, core dumped is thrown. I get the data from a file that it's ensured to be in the correct format.

It fails when there are still names to read from the file (checked with the debugger)

**Main**

```
Category *category = NULL;
memoryAllocate(&category);
```

**Memory Allocation**

```
memoryAllocate(Category **category){

 int elements;
 char name[NAME];
 int i = 0;
 FILE *fPeces;

  [...]

    //Get the number of elements from the file
    fscanf(fPeces, "%d", &elements);
    *category = (Category *)malloc(sizeof(Category) * elements));
    if(*category == NULL){
        //ERROR
    }
    else{

        while(i < elements){

            fgets(name, NAME, fPeces);
            strcpy(category[i]->categoryName, name);
            i++;

        }
}
```

**Structure**

```
typedef struct categoria {
    char categoryName[NAME];
    int part_num;
    Parts *parts;
} Category;
```

**FILE** (first number is the number of categories and the rest are the names)

```
6
category 1
category 2
category 3
category 4
category 5
category 6
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post a [mcve].  thanks.

Comment: it will not work `!feof(fPeces))`

Comment: In the while loop condition don't check for feof, ckeck for the number of elements.

Comment: I have checked the number of elements and it does not work either. It fails when I still have elements int the file. For example it fails when i == 3 having elements == 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're derefencing the wrong thing in your while loop. This line:

```
strcpy(category[i]->categoryName, name);
```

Should be:

```
strcpy((*category)[i].categoryName, name);
```

Editorial notes:

1. This problem is why I recommend minimizing the use of nested pointers where possible - it gets confusing fast. Instead of using `*category` all over the place, allocate that array locally:

   ```
   Category *myArray = malloc(elements * sizeof *myArray);
   ```

   Do your work with it:

   ```
   strcpy(myArray[i].name, name);
   ```

   And then only when you're done, copy that pointer into the output parameter:

   ```
   *category = myArray;
   ```
2. `while(!feof(...` is [always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).
3. [Don't cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc?rq=1) the result of `malloc`.

Comment: After changing the nested pointers to a local allocation and copying the output parameter everything is working perfectly, thanks.

Comment: Great - do you understand the problem with the code as you originally had it?

Comment: Yes, it was really confusing the nested pointers and I had some trouble with it. Also with the wrong usage of feof()